# Carrying two iPads (and other electronics) to India from USA

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, india, electronic-items, import-taxes

I will be taking two iPads (one iPad Air and one iPad Mini) to India from the USA. One of them I bought in India (I have the receipt) and one I bought while in the US. I am not carrying a laptop with me.

I am also carrying two Apple TV with me, inside my checked in luggage and maybe couple wristwatches as well.

Will there be any problem with customs in India?

Comment: So you're trying to avoid paying taxes on something bought overseas?

Comment: No, he's asking how much duty, if any, is payable.

Comment: @jpatokal not from his question - he's asking if there's any problems...

Comment: I have a similar question. I read the document at http://www.cbec.gov.in/trvler-guide_ason11June2014.pdf . But I'm still confused. I'll carry two used laptops (more than 6 months old) with me. Would they be included in the 75,000  limit (for professionals) or not ?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you declare everything you bought overseas and/or cannot produce evidence they were purchased in India, you won't have a problem. Note, however, you will probably owe import duty & taxes for those items you take home that didn't originate there.

For an example of what you may expect to pay, you could try [this calculation page](http://www.dutycalculator.com/country-guides/Import-duty-taxes-when-importing-into-India/).

Also note that putting some of the items in your checked in luggage does not obviate you of the requirement to declare.

EDIT: Per jpatokal's comment, the calculator I've linked here is for commercial entities and he found a [more useful one for individual travelers](http://www.dutycalculator.com/country-guides/Import-duty-taxes-when-importing-into-India/).

Comment: That duty calculator is for *commercial* importers.  An entirely separate set of rules applies to personal imports: http://www.cbec.gov.in/trvler-guide_ason22may2013.pdf

Comment: @jpatokal I've added the link you provided to my answer.